# Why is there an apostrophe in "h'm"?

Tags: etymology, contractions, apostrophe

By that I refer to the sound people make when they're thinking. Most people write "hm" nowadays, so they may not know of this, but traditionally, people wrote it as "h'm". The apostrophe can't indicate elision, since "h'm" is an onomatopoeia, so why is it there?

Comment: Hum... let me think about that... Ho-hum! - I've got it!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hmm...

Comment: @Hugo: Hmmm... I think that's just being lazy - if you're going accept words without vowels, you may as well go the whole hog and give it **three** m's.

Comment: Thomas Hardy has "h'm" in *Jude the Obscure.*

Comment: Twice.  `"H'm!" said Jude, with a sense of sacrilege.` and `"H'm. That's a cheap sneer. I ought to have waited, unquestionably."` http://www.gutenberg.org/files/153/153-h/153-h.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as FF suggests, a spelling like *"h'm"* might be thought proper by some people, if they believe  -- like all proper spelling, this is a matter of faith, though not morals -- that *"h'm"*, a breathy voiced nasal resonant with voiceless onset used to mark a brief pause for ostensible thought, is **actually** short for *hum*, a word describing resonance in general, including breathy nasal resonance.

Of course, why not? Surely such people exist, and for them that's a proper spelling. Certainly *hum* is a part of *ho, hum,* another phatic phrase mimicking the headshake or eyeroll of boredom -- though that is close to the opposite of what *"h'm"* means. Still, everybody makes up their own language, and that's the way they made **theirs** up.

For others, who see no more connection between *"h'm"* and *hum* than they do between *bug* and *humbug* or *pole* and *polar*, the apostrophe (being silent in any event and therefore superfluous in onomatopoeia, as the OQ points out) may be dropped without penalty.

[Punctuation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-Punctuation.pdf), especially of apostrophe's, is very chaotic and cannot be depended on in general; in onomatopoeia it is even less valuable. In fact, since search engines ignore punctuation, chaotic apostrophization seems to incur no penalty any more.

Comment: haha - I couldn't *quite* pin down why I was diffident about putting *ho, hum* in the commment. Of course you're right - oftentimes it means *"I can't even be bothered to think about [whatever you're saying]"*, whereas *hmm* often means *"That's interesting - let me think about it for a second"*. Even when it means *"I disagree, and might be about to explain why"*, it still indicates that you are in fact mentally engaging with [whatever was said].

Answer (score 0):

The [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (subscription required) finds the interjection *h'm* as early as 1854 in Thackeray.  But it just refers to the earlier inerjections *hem* and *hum* with the same meaning.